# Problem in getting the parseInt(data) return NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a peculiar problem with getting an integer from an ajax response. Whenever I call the following code, parseInt(data) returns NaN despite data being a string.

```
function(data)  //return information back from jQuery's get request
            {

                $('#progress_container').fadeIn(100);   //fade in progress bar  
                $('#progress_bar').width(data +"%");    //set width of progress bar based on the $status value (set at the top of this page)
                $('#progress_completed').html(parseInt(data) +"%"); //display the % completed within the progress bar
            }
```

Comment: what is the value you send as data to this function?

Comment: You should really try to debug it or at least alert the "data" that is actually got passed to your code. I bet the problem is there.

Comment: You should also be in the habit of always passing the 2nd `radix` parameter to `parseInt` which is the number base. Usually you'll want that to be 10. If your number string happens to have a leading zero, and you don't use radix, it'll be treated as octal: bad.

Comment: try with base `parseInt(data,10)`

Comment: would a `try` `catch` make sense here if you don't know what you're getting back?

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of this line:

```
$('#progress_completed').html(parseInt(data) +"%");
```

It seems like you are trying to insert a percentage as HTML into the #progress_completed element.  You mentioned that `data` is a string, then why are you converting it into an Integer then concatenating another string (the % is a string)?

```
parseInt(data) + "%"
```

This statement above creates a string.  If you say that `data` is truly a string, then all you need would be:

```
$('#progress_completed').html(data +"%");
```

I'd suggest adding console.log(data) to check the value of data first to be sure.

Comment: hi every one thanks for your kind consideration,i also try the radix parseInt(data , 10).

Comment: when i try to alert(data.length) it give me the result of 109,

Comment: Can you just try alert(data).  Knowing the length of the data does no good here.